# How to convert <NSCoding> Objects to CoreData?

Tags: objective-c, core-data-migration, nscoding

I have a custom class, say the class Person, which implements the NSCoding protocol. I used to save my application's data using:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:{an array containing my Person objects} toFile:pathToSave];
```

Now I want to switch to CoreData and Cocoa bindings. I think I know the very basics of CoreData, but I don't know how I can import my old unarchived Array into CoreData....

Can someone help me with this or send me a link to a tutorial?

Thanks a lot!
Nick

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that. I will accept answers in the future. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to automagically turn your archived objects to Core Data.

This article is a good start to what you should do:

http://www.mentalfaculty.com/mentalfaculty/Blog/Entries/2010/4/17_Keyed-Archiving_to_Core_Data_Migration.html

In a nut shell, you will replace your `<NSCoding>` compliant subclasses with `NSManagedObject` subclasses and do the migration manually.

Comment: Sadly this linked page doesn't exist anymore.